# android app view web content

Tags: android, eclipse

I am currently creating my own app which will basically display my web app. I have eclipse and I also have the android plug in for it.

but how can I get my web app to basically display what is online?  I am looking for a 100% frame or something. I can not find this option anywhere.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can view your website in android application using android [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

.java code:

```
String websiteUrl = "Your URL goes here";
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(websiteUrl);

    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi AReader. This does not work. I have added both lots of text to the activity_main.xml file however as you stated .java for the 2nd code im guessing this needs to go into a file of its own right? because the code <java>TEXT 2</java> does not work. how do i load up a separate .java page im still learning eclipse thanks.

Comment: @KevHopwood This code will go in an activity file of your Android application. I would suggest you to check some basic Android application tutorials. [Refer this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/)